# ASP.NET Core: Session Id Always Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Today started a brand new ASP.NET Core site.  Followed the instructions to add sessions.  We print out the Session ID on the index page, and it is always unique.

I figure it may be cookie compliance, so I nuked all cookies, both in Chrome's advanced settings and debugger.  But the banner won't reappear for me to accept.

I also tried simply disabling CheckConsentNeeded, but that also had no impact.

Pretty much a duplicate from the default project plus MSDN, except for the tweaks described above:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; //require https
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; //true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Session id changes until you actually store something, the id is fixed then.

Comment: You are correct! This makes me wonder about a few more things.  First, why was that designed that way?  Second and more importantly for my progress, surely we're not expected in every controller end point to make sure the session is set up correctly; is there a normal way confirm/initialize the session?  In old ASP.NET, we used attributes, which I have yet to learn how to upgrade.

Comment: ASP.NET Core still uses attributes (assuming you're talking about something like the AuthorizeAttribute, AllowAnonymousAttribute, etc.). As an example, I have a custom ActionFilterAttribute which I decorate most of my controllers with and which checks my custom principal for a specific claim - you could do something similar with a session value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wiktor Zychla was correct in the first comment: you must assign any data for the ID to stick.

I simply assigned any data to the session in my controller:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Set("What", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        }
```

After that, `HttpContext.Session.Id` did not change, as one would expect.

As my first foray into ASP.NET Core from ASP.NET Framework, I didn't expect that, and I am sure I won't be the last!

Comment: This seems to work, however I have to include this code for *every* `IActionResult` method in every controller... seems horribly kludgy.

Comment: Correct, my answer is not a "best practices" answer.  It's a "this is the bare minimum you need to get expected behavior" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Zoop’s answer inspired me, but as my comment suggests, it becomes messy should your application have a lot of actions. Based on their answer, I came up with this:

Create a base controller for your application if you don’t have one already. Derive all of your existing controllers from that controller. Override the base method that behaves like the old `Page_Load` from ASP.NET. `OnActionExecuting` gets invoked before any action code does.

```
public class MyApplicationController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        HttpContext.Session.Set("What", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is an imperfect solution as well. I have abandoned trying to use `Session` at all in my MVC project. This will work in cases where you don't do anything but `GET` and `POST`. (e.g., `$ajax` will mess this up.)

Answer (score 0):

About the question.

Your session id is according to the `Cookie` of client.
You can check the value in Chrome Devtool.

The default key is `.AspNetCore.Session`.

[image]

If your `.AspNetCore.Session` or Cookie is null,Your server will automate create a new session id.

So,check your request headers first.

In the last img,You can see `Host` is not same with `Origin`,with the CORS problem,the requst will not include `Cookie` by default.

You can add  [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) header in requst to solve the problem.

In `axios` you can do like this:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
   withCredentials: true,
   baseURL: BASE_URL
})
instance.get('/todos')
```